# java 9: JLink created invalid images - missing module executable script

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, jlink

I am creating a sample application with 3 modules `user`, `dept` and `account`. In my user module, I have a main class and compile my modules with the following command:

```
javac -d target --module-source-path src $(find -name "*.java")
```

After compiling, execute following command for run:

```
java -p target -m com.user/com.user.info.Launcher
```

The output after running java modules are successful. But when trying to create runtime image using `jlink` the image created successfully but module executable script is not there. For create an image, I am using the following command:

```
jlink --module-path $JAVA_HOME/jmods:target --add-modules com.user --output my-app
```

In, runtime image, I have `bin` directory, but this directory contains only `java` and `keynote` script. I am expecting user main class script as well, for executing my application.

My Java version as below:

```
java version "9-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+165)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+165, mixed mode)
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Afaik `jlink` does not create an executable. It just creates a runtime image of a VM that only has the modules you need.

Comment: But in the greeting sample that mention in open jdk, have the script of greeting

Comment: Can you link the place where you see that? I don't see it on here: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start

Comment: Yes this is not there, I think I was reading in Java 9 modularity book by http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://shop.oreilly.com/product/mobile/0636920049494.do&grqid=q1IU6bWs&hl=en-IN&geid. Actually I am using lots of resources for reading, that's why, I was little bit confused

Comment: Still, the thing is, if this image contains all required module, then why we are not directly launch our application from image? If not, how can we use image for our application?

Comment: Your own module is included in the image. With the `java` binary in the `bin` folder, you can use `java com.user.info.Launcher` to launch the application.

Comment: Superb feature, thanks @Jorn for your help. Please post your answer, so I can accept.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`jlink` creates a runtime VM image in which it includes only the modules that are needed.

Since you specified `--add-modules com.user` the image will include the `com.user` module, and all of the modules it (directly or indirectly) depends on.

You can run your application by using the `java` binary in the `bin` folder of the generated image, and using the command:

```
java com.user.info.Launcher
```

---

You can also have `jlink` generate a launcher script using the `--launcher <command>=<module>/<main>` option. In your case you could do something like:

```
jlink --module-path $JAVA_HOME/jmods:target --add-modules com.user --output my-app --launcher launch=com.user/com.user.info.Launcher
```

And after that, you can just use `launch` from the `bin` directory to run the application.

Comment: Thanks @Jorn, Java always rocks

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara I found what you were describing. I tried out some things and found out there is a `--launcher` option to generate a launch script with `jlink`. I added some information to the answer.