# How do I run images generated by JDK 9 jlink?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system, jlink

I follow the Jigsaw [quickstart here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start). I successfully ran the `jlink` command given:

```
jlink --module-path $JAVA_HOME/jmods:mlib --add-modules com.greetings --output greetingsapp
```

That produces a "runtime image" which is an exploded directory structure that looks like:

```
~ tree -d greetingsapp
greetingsapp
├── bin
├── conf
│   └── security
│       └── policy
│           ├── limited
│           └── unlimited
├── include
│   └── darwin
├── legal
│   └── java.base
└── lib
    ├── jli
    ├── security
    └── server
```

How do I run this? I was expecting a binary executable, not an exploded directory tree.

The `bin` directory has a `java` and a `keytool`. I don't see any .jar files or .class files to run via the bundled `java` executable.

Comment: I answered this one a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085367

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To run, do this:

```
greetingsapp/bin/java -m com.greetings/com.greetings.Main
```

Or, you can have jlink build a launcher script that does this

```
jlink --module-path $JAVA_HOME/jmods:mlib --add-modules com.greetings --output greetingsapp --launcher launch=com.greetings/com.greetings.Main
```

and then run with:

```
greetingsapp/bin/launcher
```

---

Form the same documentation :-

```
$ java -p mods -m com.greetings/com.greetings.Main
```

could be executed to run the `Main` class from the module structure without linking using `jshell` as well.

---

Also,  `jlink` is the linker tool and can be used to link a set of modules, along with their transitive dependencies, to create a custom modular run-time image called as *[Modular Runtime Images](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220)* which can be accomplished using the [JMOD tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jmod.htm#JSWOR-GUID-0A0BDFF6-BE34-461B-86EF-AAC9A555E2AE) introduced with Java 9 modules.
As pointed out in comments and answered by [@Jorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44085961/1746118) if you simply intend to execute the main class.

> You can run your application by using the java binary in the bin
>   folder of the generated image, and using the command:
>
> ```
> java com.greetings.Main
> ```

---

On the other hand, an example of creating a JMOD file to be used as a module further is as :

```
jmod create --class-path mods/com.greetings --cmds commands
  --config configfiles --header-files src/h --libs lib
  --main-class com.greetings.Main --man-pages man --module-version 1.0
  --os-arch "x86_x64" --os-name "Mac OS X"
  --os-version "10.10.5" greetingsmod
```

**EDIT**: Expanded + clarified to have the answer that I was looking for.

Comment: That first command doesn't use jlink or the output generated by jlink at all. That uses the system Java and the compiled .class files in the `mods` directory.

Comment: @clay correct . that's what I had mentioned as well *from the module structure.*..updated it to make it clear.

Comment: an extra question would be: how do you debug the custom image? The -Xdebug doesn't work

Comment: If someone build with a launcher script like above. the run command should be `greetingsapp/bin/launch` instead of `greetingsapp/bin/launcher`